# Best Distribution to Approximate this Histogram

Tags: probability-distributions

Given the histogram below, what common distribution would be well fit to this data i.e. Beta, skewed normal. I want to use the data as a prior in Bayesian analysis so want to approximate it by a distribution in the exponential family to make this easier to do analytically.

[image: Histogram]

We can ignore the high values at 0 and the value at 0.75 as they are errors/outliers.

Comment: The histogram itself. Your question doesn't really make sense unless you have some model in mind about how the numbers were generated.

Comment: I was wondering whether it looked like any commonly studied distributions. The data is necessarily between 0 and 1. I was initially thinking of a Beta distribution but when I estimated the parameters with my data it was not such a good fit.

Comment: One problem with such questions is that if you choose a different bin size / bandwidth, you might get a very different plot out. In particular, the little mode at 0.1 is of interest ... and may suggest you have a bimodal distribution ... which may become more apparent with a smaller bandwidth ... or appear to disappear with more smoothing with a larger bandwidth.